# global image resources in QML

Tags: qml, qt5

I'd like to use some common images for my user interface across many QML files. The Image item's source property seems to always be relative to the place where the QML was loaded from.

Is there a way to have a global set of images available?
I'd prefer to load them from the application resource area.

Comment: check this [QtQuick 5.0: Deploying QML Applications](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtquick/qtquick-deployment.html)

Comment: Good find! That lead me to here: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/resources.html   which explains what I needed. If you'd like to post it as an answer I will give you credit for the solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check this QtQuick 5.0: [Deploying QML Applications](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtquick/qtquick-deployment.html) :)

The "alias" option on file nodes allows globally accessible resources ( as noted [here](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/resources.html) )